# In C what is the difference between a normal array and one declared with #define?

Tags: c, arrays

I just started learning C and I was wondering if there is a difference between an array declared like this one:
`int m[10][5];` 
and an array declared like this:

```
#define NL 10
#define NC 5
int m[NL][NC];
```

I tought that the memory allocated might be different,but i'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#define`'s are "preprocessor directives". The C preprocessor (CPP) is basically a program that is run by your compiler before actually processing your C code.

For your `#define`'s, the preprocessor basically does a "search and replace" for `NL` and `NC`, replacing with `10` and `5`, respectively. It does this without much understanding of C. (In fact, you could run the C preprocessor on any kind of text file and have it do the same search and replace.)

To get `gcc` or `clang` to stop after running the preprocessor, use the `-E` option and it'll write the preprocessor results to stdout.

Here's an example of having GCC stop after running the preprocessor on your source code:

```
$ gcc -E andre.c
# 1 "andre.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "andre.c"


int m[10][5];
```

As you can see, after running the preprocessor, `NL` and `NC` have been replaced with the text you supplied in their `#define`'s.

If you're using a compiler other than `gcc` or `clang`, check its documentation for how to stop processing after running the preprocessor. Often, preprocessed source code has the extension `.i`.

(On my machine, `cpp andre.c` does the exact same thing as the call to `gcc` above.)

Answer (score 1):

The C/C++ macros will be replaced by the compiler with inline code and there is no difference between declaration with #define and the inline code.